# Find null reference inside Asp Mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, null

I'm trying to correct a null reference exception in a Mvc Controller.
I can't debug in Visual Studio because there are query to a database reachable only on the server.
Now I have to read all the code and correct all the situation that might causes the exception or there is another way to know which is the exact variable accessed with null value?
The debug yellow screen only tells me that the exception is inside the controller's code.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of server is the application running on? IIS?

Comment: The app is running on IIS 6

Answer (score 1):

> The debug yellow screen only tells me that the exception is inside the controller's code.

The YSOD is probably also highlighting the line of code on which this exception occurs. So all that's left is to fix it. Also if you have access to the server you could use [`remote debugging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx).

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   MyClass.ParseProduct(ProductClass prod) +18267 What is the incremental '18267' on the right?

Comment: It's an IL offset. If you want to get line numbers you need to ship the corresponding PDB of the assembly on your webserver.

Comment: Sorry, I've searched but it's unclear to me what does mean to ship the pdb file. Could you give me some link? Thanks. In old aspx I had the information about the exact variable the caused the exception, why not in mvc?

Comment: Each assembly (.DLL) file has a corresponding (.PDB) file. In the settings of Visual Studio when compiling you could specify what debug information is included in this PDB file. http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know